# The Scripts files are disable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

I  just changed element's id `<li class="dropdown" id="login-modal" >` after that the scripts files doesn't works and disable in browsers like firefox and chrome to make it clearer see this image
[Image of problem](https://ibb.co/dpTKWK)
before that i updated my jquery It may be a problem her?

Comment: Nothing is clear. Seems that the script expect the previous ID to work

Comment: @IsraGab I can not say this more clearly

Comment: @IsraGab Yes Exactly I don't know what's the problem , before that i updated my jquery It may be a problem her?؟

Comment: scripts can't be disable. Scripts can be not found by the browser. Update your jquery can be a problem of course. If your script only support a specific version of jquery, it's not sure it would work with other versions

Comment: What answer are you expecting?

Comment: @IsraGab but i use inspect element and the links of script file are disable i mean they are not working

Comment: @IsraGab Please see the image

Comment: can you please try on chrome? open the console (f12) then go to the script tag, then ctrl+p and type the script name. Tell us if you can see it there

Comment: @IsraGab Yes I saw it but The structure of my site is broken

Comment: What do you mean by structure broken? Is your site on the web? can I check it by myself?

Comment: I run my project in localhost

Comment: @IsraGab see this image https://ibb.co/dpTKWK

Comment: @IsraGab You can see the links doesn't works and disable and the structure of my site is broken